# Intercambiar clases con Jquery ToggleClass

Tags: jquery, css

estoy tratando de mostrar/ocultar un submenu cuando hago clic en el item de dicho menu (OBRAS).

Por defecto mi submenu esta "oculto" con CSS

```
.children {
   position: fixed;
   opacity: 0;
}
```

y necesito que al hacer clic lo muestre intercambiando con esta clase

```
.children-1 {
    position: inherit;
    opacity: 1;
    left: auto;
    margin-left: 30px;
    transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

El script que estoy utilizando es este

```
    jQuery(function ($) {
       $( 'children' ).click(function() {
            $( this ).toggleClass( 'children-1' );
       });
    });
```

El sitio es http://iglesias.coroleu.com/

Gracias

Comment: Hola, en lugar de poner un enlace a una página externa, deberías poner el código HTML, JS y CSS necesario para reproducir el problema en la propia pregunta. Los enlaces se rompen o dejan de funcionar y entonces la pregunta dejaría de tener sentido. El editor cuenta con la posibilidad de añadir snippets (al pulsar el icono que se parece a `<>`), para más información sobre cómo usarlo, lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El click debe ir en el parent de lo que esta oculto.
Aqui va un ejemplo funcional:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>submenuclickopen</title>
<style>
  #menu ul, #menu ul li {display:block;padding:0;margin:0;}
  #menu ul {list-style:none;background:#eee;}
  #menu ul li {display:block;width:25%}
  #menu ul.mainmenu li {float:left;text-align:center;background:#ddd;}
  #menu ul.submenu li {float:none;text-align:left;background:#ccc;width:100%;}
  #menu ul.mainmenu a {padding:5px 10px;}
  #menu ul li.separador {text-indent:-9999px;border-bottom:1px solid black;height: 5px;}
  #menu ul.submenu {display:none;}

  #menu ul.mainmenu li.mostrarsubmenu ul.submenu {display:block;}

  /* descomentar para rollover */
  /* #menu ul.mainmenu li:hover ul.submenu {display:block;} */

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
 <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="#main1">main menu item 1</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
       <li><a href="#sub11">submenu 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#sub12">submenu 2</a></li>
       <li class="separador">---</li>
       <li><a href="#sub13">submenu 3</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
    <li><a href="#main2">main menu item 2</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
       <li><a href="#sub21">submenu 1</a></li>
       <li class="separador">---</li>
       <li><a href="#sub22">submenu 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#sub23">submenu 3</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
    <li><a href="#main3">main menu item 3</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
       <li><a href="#sub31">submenu 1</a></li>
       <li class="separador">---</li>
       <li><a href="#sub32">submenu 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#sub33">submenu 3</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script>
$("#menu ul.mainmenu > li > a").click(function(){
// descomentar esta línea es para ocultar los otros submenus
/*    $(this).parent().parent().find("li").removeClass("mostrarsubmenu"); */
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("mostrarsubmenu");
});
</script>
</html>
```